# Determine if NSString's first character is a number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, numbers

I just wanted to know how i can determine whether a NSStrings first character is a number.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
BOOL hasLeadingNumberInString(NSString* s) {
if (s)
    return [s length] && isnumber([s characterAtIndex:0]);
else
    return NO;
```

}

In the event you are handling many NSStrings at once (like looping through an array) and you want to check each one for formatting like leading numbers, it's better practice to include checks so that you do not try evaluating an empty or nonexistent string.

Example:

```
NSString* s = nil; //Edit: s needs to be initialized, at the very least, to nil.
hasLeadingNumberInString(s);          //returns NO
hasLeadingNumberInString(@"");        //returns NO
hasLeadingNumberInString(@"0123abc"); //returns YES
```

Comment: i like this one. Lots of apps crash when an unexpected nil or zero length string comes along. Developers never try leaving the field blank, or other oddities.

Comment: NSString* s;
hasLeadingNumberInString(s);          //returns NO is not going to work, as s is a random number, not nil. (minor point the method is right, just use NSString* s = nil; for the test.

Comment: Tom is correct. My method assumes that s is, at the very least, initialize to nil or something else.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. You can do:

```
NSString *s = ...; // a string
unichar c = [s characterAtIndex:0];
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
    // you have a number!
}
```

Comment: Or even isdigit([s characterAtIndex:0])?

Answer (score 7):

I can think of two ways to do it. You could use

```
[string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]].location == 0
```

Or you could use

```
[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[string characterAtIndex:0]]
```

Comment: I would not use either of these.  They scan the string o(N).  If you only care about the first character, a o(1) solution should be used.

Comment: The second does not scan the string. Depending on just how NSCharacterSet is implemented, it might scan the set or it might be a test much like your answer below.

Comment: It also could be that the decimalDigitCharacterSet throws an alloced autoreleased object out that when called lots of times will kill performance.

Answer (score 5):

Check the return value of:

```
[myString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];
```

If the `location` value of the returned range is `0`, you have a match at the first character.

Comment: This could be really slow for long strings, and if the user inputs the stting it could be any length. (see order (N) comment)

Comment: Have you actually checked that the method scans the entire string? It would be really badly implemented if it did. From the documentation: "Finds and returns the range in the receiver of the first character from a given character set." It sounds to me likes it stops once it found a match.

Comment: Thinking more about it, what I said above should be true at least if there is a positive match on the first character. If not, the string will indeed be parsed completely (in the worst case when there isn't a match in the entire string).

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using a call that scans the entire string, it is best to pull out the first char then see what it is:

```
char test = [myString characterAtIndex:0];
if (test >= '0' && test <= '9')
  return YES
else
  return NO
```